# How does the FPGA determines the contents of a LUT without using logic gates?

Tags: architecture, fpga

Let's we want to perform **Y = ABCD** 
I know that a LUT acts like a memory block. Since FPGA uses LUTS instead of logic gates, how does it know that it needs to feed the LUT with a truth table for a 4 variable AND function without logic gates? How does the calculation happen?

Comment: Although I see you've already gotten at least one answer, you may have gotten many more  if this had been posted on the electronics site within the Stack Exchange Network. Located at: https://electronics.stackexchange.com Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The choice to use a LUT versus gates can be driven by the user or the synthesizer.  Depending on settings, the synthesizer can favor one versus the other.  When the LUT is used, it should be thought of as memory and in fact the bit file that is used to program the FPGA will contain the contents of the LUT.  It isn't calculated as truth table at imaging.  Rather the synthesizer identified the possibility of using a LUT, and then it may have reduced some logic to what the LUT contents would be (read as calculate I guess) and then made sure the FPGA would have that LUT content when it was imaged.

In your example above you can take a single bit memory with 16 locations (4 bits of address and 1 bit of data output) and model the 4 input AND gate.  All address of the LUT, except for one will be populated with 0 and only address 0xF will have a 1.  This would effectively be realized in the bit file for the LUT contents.

Comment: so is it more like it identifies that it is an AND operation, and then feeds the LUT addresses with appropriate bits? Then does it mean there's a control line that gets feed into the LUT, like 000 -> AND, 001-> OR, etc similar to ALU?

Comment: That is certainly one way the synthesizer can work.  There could be a control line on the LUT and one way that it might get used is as one of the 4 inputs to your AND gate.  So three address lines where 3'b111 outputs a 1, but only when CONTROL is asserted.  Thus CONTROL and all Address lines are 1's giving you an output of 1.   That is one way a 4 input AND could have been realized.  There are other ways too.

Comment: Oh I think I mis-understood the follow up question.   A LUT could have a control line.  But it doesn't change a logic function of the LUT.  LUT's a like a memory.  Memories don't have a set of control that makes them behave like and AND or an OR specifically.  They have address lines and data at the address in their simplest form.  Write our your 16 addresses. For an OR gate,any case where an address has a bit set, (ALL of them except 4'F0) you will output a 1'b1.  You can load the memory to behave like an AND or an OR.